# Invoke-WebRequest / Invoke-RestMethod failed with error underlying connection closed

Tags: rest, powershell

I have an existing REST API that accept x-www-form-urlencoded. The API need parameter apikey, and tested successfully in Postman as shown below.

[image]

However I need to invoke this API using Powershell.Below is my code :

```
$params = @{"apikey"="abcd1234"}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:3030/api/v1/usergroupsync -Method POST -Body $params
#also tried below, no avail.
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:3030/api/v1/usergroupsync -Method POST -Body $params
```

However I encountered this error :

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a receive At line:14 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:3030/api/v1/usergroupsync -Method POST -...
+==============================================================================
  + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperations: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HTTTpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebcmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.InvokeWebRequest
```

If I remove -Body, there is no error, and Response was as expected "API Key is not valid" which means my REST API validate correctly. 
[image]

So I suspect the reason if my issue is on the body? Any idea on how to solve this issue?

PS Version is 4.0.0

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
 4      0      -1     -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the -Header switch to pass your parameters. Though `Invoke-WebRequest` support header, I recommend using `Invoke-RestMethod` as it also return the Headers.

Try something like,

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri http://localhost:3030/api/v1/usergroupsync -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) -Header @{"apikey"=$apiKey}
```

Check [this](https://www.lavinski.me/calling-a-rest-json-api-with-powershell/) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) for more information

Comment: Yeah, I already did the workaround by moving to headers, however I still intriqued on why I can't pass it in the body?

Comment: In general, header can be modified by certain entities (over http). Meaning, a proxy server can modify ur parameter if required. This might throw more light to it: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/277343